# Facebook Achievements Localization

Tags: facebook, localization, achievements

I would like to ask if there is a way to localize Facebook achievements (developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements/).
I have two problems:

1. **Achievement story localization**
   I've set additional language of the application according to this doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/internationalization.
   When I change language of the user and then look at the Activity Log, the achievement story (e.g. John earned SUPER ACHIEVEMENT in SUPER GAME.) isn't translated. Because I don't create this story I would assume that it will be translated automatically like other stories (e.g. John played SUPER GAME. -> John hat SUPER GAME gespielt.)
2. **Achievement HTML localization**
   I can't find a way how to localize achievement HTML page.
   This page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/ is only what I found. I've read it but I don't know how to apply it to achievements.

Thanks